# Algoritmo de Capicua não é impresso como deveria

Tags: c, algoritmo

Programa para encontrar todos os números Capicua (um número que é lido da mesma forma de trás para frente e de frente para trás) entre 10 e 500. Tentei fazer assim mas os valores não estão a ser impressos.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i,num,inv,res;
    inv = 0;

    for(i=10;i<=500;i++){
        while(num != 0){
        res = num % 10;
        inv = (inv * 10) + res;
        num = num / 10;
    }
        if(i == inv)
            printf("%d ",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez o maior motivo para isso acontecer provavelmente é que não está atribuindo um valor inicial para `num`, já começa dar besteira aí porque depende da sorte para a memória ter um valor útil ali. E mais, depois que ele fizer o cálculo dentro do primeiro laço do `for` o `num` não é reinicializado, então ele pega o valor que terminou o passo anterior, que certamente não é o desejado.

Isso acontece porque algumas pessoas ensinam C de 30 anos atrás e não o atual, aí quem aprende fixa a ideia de declarar variáveis antes e não perto do uso como deve ser o mais correto. Junte-se a isso uma organização de código melhor fica mais fácil enxergar esse tipo de erro. Mesmo que você saiba que toda variável deveria ser inicializada antes de usar ainda poderia "comer bola" e não ver pela falta de organização e por ter a declaração da variável muito antes do que precisa dela.

Inicializando `num` em todos os passos de execução do `for` com o valor de `i` porque é o número que será analisado, funciona perfeitamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 10; i <= 500; i++) {
        int inv = 0, num = i;
        while (num != 0) {
            inv = (inv * 10) + num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        if (i == inv) printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Rg97FO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Capicuiac). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Capicuia.c).

Não sou muito fã porque fica menos legível, mas se quiser fazer mais curto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 10; i <= 500; i++) {
        int inv = 0, num = i;
        do inv = (inv * 10) + num % 10;
        while ((num /= 10) != 0);
        if (i == inv) printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```