# Números Palíndromos em C

Tags: c

Preciso criar um algoritmo que verifique se um número é palíndromo ou não. Eu resolvi fazer esse algoritmo usando um número como uma string, porém o programa sempre retorna que os números não são Palíndromos.

```
char numero[10], numeroInvertido[10];
int i, j;

printf("Digite um numero : ");
scanf("%s",numero);

for (i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(numero); i++, j++){
    numeroInvertido[j] = numero[i];
}

if (numeroInvertido == numero)
    printf("E um palindromo \n");
else
    printf("Nao e um palindromo \n");
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448607/101

Comment: A comparação de strings em C não se faz através do operador `==` e sim com a função `strcmp` de `<string.h>`. Além disso uma string sempre deve conter o caractere terminador '\0'. Na realidade sua comparação está verificando se o endereço de `numeroInvertido` é igual ao endereço de `numero`.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas modificações no seu código, acredito que mesmo depois de resolver a **comparação**, o programa **não** estava gerando o **número invertido**. Tratei esses e aqui está o resultado:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char numero[10], numeroInvertido[10];
  int i, j;

  printf("Digite um numero : ");
  scanf("%s", numero);

  for (i = 0, j = strlen(numero) - 1; i < strlen(numero); i++, j--) {
    numeroInvertido[j] = numero[i];
  }

  if (!(strcmp(numeroInvertido, numero)))
    printf("E um palindromo \n");
  else
    printf("Nao e um palindromo \n");

  return 0;
}
```

Resultados:

```
Digite um numero : 12321
E um palindromo
```

```
Digite um numero : 1234
Nao e um palindromo
```